# Microsoft Analysis Services - Delete server objects and Visual Studio 2022 fails to deploy any cubes

Tags: ssas, olap, analysisservices

I am testing out MS AS for possible use as an OLAP cube on our project.

I've been using the Visual Studio 2022 plugin for about a week and it all seems straightforward.

Just now I deleted a deployed setup from AS server and now when I build to deploy a cube it fails with:

**The 'Global Config' cube was not found in the 'TestBonds' database on the '' server.**

This is with 'Deploy All' set which I'd have thought forces it.

Global Config is my datasource name. I've tried a new project, inheriting the datasource, but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out although that error message could be more descriptive!

Essentially it will not deploy, which is a good thing I guess :), until you work through any errors in the build panel.

I had some circular references and other 'relationship issues' :).

I am still working out what is what as I come from a totally different OLAP building experience with Java and ActivePivot (which I think is based on the original MS AS anyway! :)).

So if you see weird errors and it will not deploy, work through any errors to get rid of them! I also changed the deploy settings to:

- Processing Option: Full
- Server Mode: Deploy All

to be on the safe side.